# How to decode JSON using PHP in three listing columns?

Tags: php, css, json, foreach, decode

I'm new using JSON and PHP.
I have a big list of products in JSON that is being decoded through PHP and I need this list to be splited in 3 columns. How can I do this?
Here is the code I'm using now:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="section-title">
        <ul class="dados">
            <?php
                $url = 'http://myurl/consult';
                $data = file_get_contents($url);
                $characters = json_decode($data);
                foreach ($characters as $character) {
            ?>
            <li class="nomes-ies"><a href="#" class="nomes-ies"><?php echo $character->nome . '</a></li>'; } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you want 3 `<div class="col-md-4">`, right?

Comment: You might want to display the output of `$character->nome` and what you want. Is this single entry outputting 3 arrays?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use [`array_chunk()`](https://php.net/array_chunk) to split your array in three elements. Then, use a foreach on this array, around the `<div class="col-md-4">`:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://myurl/consult';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $characters = json_decode($data);
    $cols = array_chunk($characters, ceil(count($characters) / 3));
    foreach ($cols as $data) {
?>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="section-title">
        <ul class="dados">
            <?php foreach ($data as $character) { ?>
            <li class="nomes-ies"><a href="#" class="nomes-ies"><?php echo $character->nome ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } // end foreach $cols ?>
```

Note that the number of elements used in `array_chunk()` must be computed with [`ceil()`](https://php.net/ceil) to avoid to get 4 columns. The last column could have less elements than the other.

Comment: Thank you @Syscall, this was very helpfull.